# Installing CUDA toolchain in linux without botching X

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I've been trying for some time to install the CUDA toolchain (6.5) on my linux (Fedora 20 x64, GeForce GT 540M) system. The main issue is that the drivers that curently allow X to run (bumblebee-nvidia.x86_64) conflict with the real NVIDIA drivers (xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs-340.29-2.fc20.x86_64, and xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-devel-340.29-2.fc20.x86_64) that allow CUDA to run.

I had a wild party tossing bumblebee and installing CUDA only to find that on reboot X wouldn't start, and then reversing the whole process.

A friend told me that he had difficulty with the Nouveau ("Nouveau sucks" was the quote) which appears related to my bumblebee drivers (his instructions didn't work for me).

How does one go about installing the CUDA toolchain and drivers so that X starts? Sureley there's a way to get the xorg-nvidia drivers to do what bumblebee currently does?

As an additional potential solution: is it possible to have the X system run on my integrated intel graphics chip, and then use the NVidia card as compute only? 
How does one go about saying "Hey linux, use THIS chip with THESE drivers when running X"?
That would be a first step. Then somehow having those drivers coexist with the nvidia drivers and then making the nvidia drivers compute only. 
If anyone could point to a good explination of how the whole X and xorg thing works, I would be highly appreciative.

Comment: What is your video hardware? Why don't the regular drivers work?

Comment: Video hardware is described above + Intel integrated. I want CUDA to do CUDA development, and it conflicts with current drivers, and the drivers it gives doesn't play well. I will note that I was trying CUDA 6.5.

Comment: I guess I should say that the current drivers work fine. 
Its just that they cant be used with the CUDA drivers required for having the CUDA toolchain installed and then being able to run things compiled with CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

After installing CUDA, but *before* you reboot run the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf

sudo update-alternatives --set i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf

sudo ldconfig

sudo reboot
```

If the system is already broken: login to a `tty` (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>) and run the above commands from there.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. Please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).

Comment: Which CUDA Version were you using?
As I said in an earlier comment, I am using the new 6.5. I feel like this may be the problem. But Im not sure. I cannot remember if I tried 5.5 with any willingness to attack problems that I had installing it.

Comment: This is with cuda ubuntu1404-6-5-prod_6.5-19_amd64

Comment: This also has the additional effect you wanted, ie. when X loads the nvidia driver, it fails (lack of nvidia GLX?), and then removes the nvidia driver from X. This leaves X running with your original (non-nvidia) card, with the nvidia available for number crunching.

Comment: Hm. I didnt see this work.
I installed cuda using the method specified by section 3.3 in the [guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf)
Then attempted the commands you've specified.
Again was unable to get X to start.
Thankfully it was easily rolled back by yum.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid problems if you already have a working X server installation is to answer NO when the installer asks if you want it to create a new X11 configuration.

This will at least allow X11 to restart after the installation. You can then perform whatever customisations to your X11 configuration after the initial reboot when installing or upadting the NVIDIA proprietary driver. It is also good practice to make a backup of your X11 configuration file before tinkering with it. You can always go back to a known good file if you break something.